# Replace only up to N matches on a line

Tags: regex, perl

In Perl, how to write a regular expression that replaces only up to N matches per string?

I.e., I'm looking for a middle ground between `s/aa/bb/;` and `s/aa/bb/g;`. I want to allow multiple substitutions, but only up to N times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of three reliable ways. The first is to replace everything after the Nth match with itself.

```
my $max = 5;
$s =~ s/(aa)/ $max-- > 0 ? 'bb' : $1 /eg;
```

That's not very efficient if there are far more than N matches. For that, we need to move the loop out of the regex engine. The next two methods are ways of doing that.

```
my $max = 5;
my $out = '';
$out .= $1 . 'bb' while $max-- && $in =~ /\G(.*?)aa/gcs;
$out .= $1 if $in =~ /\G(.*)/gcs;
```

And this time, in-place:

```
my $max = 5;
my $replace = 'bb';
while ($max-- && $s =~ s/\G.*?\Kaa/$replace/s) {
   pos($s) = $-[0] + length($replace);
}
```

---

You might be tempted to do something like

```
my $max = 5;
$s =~ s/aa/bb/ for 1..$max;
```

but that approach will fail for other patterns and/or replacement expressions.

```
my $max = 5;
$s =~ s/aa/ba/ for 1..$max;  # XXX Turns 'aaaaaaaa'
                             #     into 'bbbbbaaa'
                             #     instead of 'babababa'
```

And of course, starting from the beginning of the string every time could be expensive.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the problem with `s/.../.../ for 1..N`. But the example has a minor flaw, `aaaa` would become `bbba` not `bbbb`.

Comment: @Qtax, Thanks. I didn't want to downvote Hubert Schölnast since he's new and his answer actually works for the specific question asked, but I doubt the OP is really working with `aa` and `bb`. So I covered why his solution is fragile here.

Comment: @ikegami it's been a long time since I've done perl, but if you could keep track of what position in the string you are and restart the regex search from there, it would fix the problem with `s/.../.../ for 1..N`. Though it would be a little ugly.

Comment: @jb., Added such a solution, but it's not that pretty either.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is not posible in regular expressions. But you can put the replacement in a for-loop:

```
my $i;
my $aa = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {
    $aa =~ s/aa/bb/;
}
print "$aa\n";
```

result:

> bbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: `for my $i (0 .. 3)` is the perl way to write it. A prettier way is `$aa =~ s/aa/bb/ for 1 .. 3`.

Comment: Maybe put a `last unless $aa =~ ...` in there for efficiency

Comment: Note that this approach can fail for some pairs of search and replacement expression  e.g. `$aa =~ s/aa/ba/;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `/e` flag  which evaluates the right side as an expression:

```
my $n = 3;    
$string =~ s/(aa)/$n-- > 0 ? "bb" : $1/ge;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the /e modifier, with which you can use
perl code to generate the replacement string:

```
  my $count = 0;
  $string =~ s{ $pattern }
              { 
                $count++;
                if ($count < $limit ) { 
                  $replace;
                } else { 
                  $&; # faking a no-op, replacing with the original match.
                }
              }xeg;
```

With perl 5.10 or later you can drop the $& (which has weird
performance complications) and use ${^MATCH} via the /p modifier

```
  $string =~ s{ $pattern }
              {
                $count++;
                if ($count < $limit ) { 
                  $replace;
                } else { 
                  ${^MATCH};
                }
              }xegp;
```

It's too bad you can't just do this, but you can't:

```
  last if $count >= $limit;
```